# Force device rotate issue on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make just one view of the landscape and other all views are on the portrait. It works but there is an issue on every second-time screen doesn't rotate at all.

Here is the scenario that I am talking about: 
[image]

On every second time, device rotation doesn't work.

**Here is my code**

`AppDelegate.swift`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}
```

`Controller1.swift`

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    AppUtility.lockOrientation(.portrait)
}
```

`DetailController.swift`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    AppUtility.lockOrientation(.landscape, andRotateTo: .landscapeLeft)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if isMovingFromParentViewController {
        AppUtility.lockOrientation(.portrait, andRotateTo: .portrait)
    }
}
```

`Code that effects the rotation`

```
struct AppUtility {

static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
    if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        delegate.orientationLock = orientation
    }
}

static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    self.lockOrientation(orientation)
    UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
}

}
```

So, How to force rotate detail view every time it loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:- Please define a below-mentioned variable in app delegate.**

```
var shouldRotate : Bool = false
```

**Step 2:- Implement the following delegate method as below.**

```
//MARK:- Set Device Orientation Delegate Method

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return shouldRotate ? .landscapeRight : .portrait
}
```

**Step 3 :- Define constant class and add "Set Portrait Orientation" and "Set Landscape Right Orientation" function in the class.**

```
//MARK:- Set Portrait Orientation
func setPortraitOrientation() {
    appDelegateInstance.shouldRotate = false
    UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
}

//MARK:- Set Landscape Right Orientation

func setLandscapeRightOrientation() {
   appDelegateInstance.shouldRotate = true
   UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
}
```

**Step 4:- Use the following code in your class (Target landscape class)**

**Step 4.1:- In view will appear call set Landscape Right Orientation function shown below.**

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    setLandscapeRightOrientation()
 }
```

**Step 4.2 :- When you leave the screen implement the following code in the action.**

```
//MARK:- Left Bar Button Tapped Delegate Method

func leftBarButtonTapped() {
    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
    setPortraitOrientation()
}
```

Happy Coding! Cheers!!